# extract real link from encrypted link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Extracting a link seems easy on regular link by using:

```
$link = $('a:eq(1)');
var real_link = $link.attr('href');
```

the hardest part is how to extract link from encrypted link like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/rm7mp8do/

if you hover to the link, on you status bar it will show you fake link like:

hxxp://this_is_fake_link

but after you click it, it will bring you to the original link:

hxxp://mg.com/ghits/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/x/x/?h=gdwagdjgawjhvjwhafgdjhwavwxdjhav

Comment: you want to get `h` parameter.

Comment: Please include the least amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue (preferably without ads) in the question itself, not only on jsfiddle.

Comment: hello mike. i want to extract the link from that ads

Answer (score -1):

You can try this php script using curl return transfer ...

```
function expand_short_url($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
    $header = curl_exec($ch);

    $fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header)); // Parse information

    for($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++)
    {
        if(strpos($fields[$i],'Location') !== false)
        {
            $url = str_replace("Location: ","",$fields[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: i dont get it. what is this? have you seen my jsfiddle? I want to extract the url from the ads using javascript

Comment: ok sorry ;) i did not get it... i thought you want to expand a short url